# Using Data from one form to another in java servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am having a Html page with form A.html and the corresponding servlet.I need to use the values of this form in another servlet and html file.So to do this i first do the following in servlet corresponding to that form

```
request.setAttribute("OName",request.getParameter("OName"));
request.setAttribute("GName",request.getParameter("GName"));
request.setAttribute("OEmail",request.getParameter("OEmail"));
request.setAttribute("OContact",request.getParameter("OContact"));
RequestDispatcher myDispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("second.html");
myDispatch.forward(request,response);
```

And then in second servlet do the following :

```
Object  OwnerName = request.getAttribute("OName");
out.println(OwnerName);
```

But when i print this then it prints null.What can be the reason .
Please help

Comment: are you sure that request.getParameter("OName") don't return NULL ?

Comment: @ahmedabobakr yeah.I am sure.Am inserting values in it.Only then on a button click moving to next html page.I even checked it in first servlet by printing their values.They are NOT null

Comment: is second.html is your second servlet url mapping?

Comment: @RameshK Yeah it is second mapping

Comment: @user3445854, `request.setAttribute("OName",request.getParameter("xxx(htmlpagename)"));` you should mention name give form html page ...

Answer (score -1):

When Setting the attribute give it a different name than the object

```
request.setAttribute("OName",request.getParameter("OName"));  // "OName" must be changed
```

so the solution is

```
request.setAttribute("XName",request.getParameter("OName"));
```

And then in second servlet do the following :

```
Object  OwnerName = request.getAttribute("XName");
out.println(OwnerName);
```

Comment: still same results..:(

Comment: I tested it, it was giving null but after the solution i suggests, it works with me,  the only different thing is that i am using jsp pages not html A.jsp and second.jsp ... also restart the server may solve that issue

Comment: Should i be passing html file in it or servlet name ? i.e RequestDispatcher myDispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("second.html");Its still give error in my case

Comment: it should be second servlet url